# Issue using own CA cert on Bluestacks emulator

Tags: certificates, bluestacks

I am trying to set up TLS interception with PolarProxy, using my own CA cert to see the clear-text payload of Android traffic. I am using BlueStacks 10 as an Android emulator. I used the procedure [at this link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/237141/how-to-get-android-11-to-trust-a-user-root-ca-without-a-private-key) to generate a CA cert and used the procedure [at this link](https://xdaforums.com/t/tutorial-how-to-install-custom-ssl-certificates-root-etc-on-bluestacks-4-5.4513773/) to place it on the BlueStacks instance. Specifically I mounted the drive for the BlueStacks instance onto a VirtualBox machine to add the cert onto the BlueStacks' drive.

I've checked that the cert is being used by PolarProxy since it shows up on the Windows machine I am hosting BlueStacks on. Further, the cert is on the machine since I see it at the /system/etc/security/cacerts folder in BlueStacks with the same permissions as the other certs on the instance. However, when I navigate to a website on BlueStacks using Chrome, Firefox, or Opera, the certificate is not trusted and I get an error. Is there a post-install step I'm missing here or something else that needs to happen for the BlueStacks instance to trust the cert?

Comment: Is your proxy certificate shown in the System CA list of Android (in settings -> security)?

Comment: That option doesn't seem to be available in the Settings app on Bluestacks unfortunately

Comment: Depending on the used Android version the list of system/user CA may be located in one of the submenues, so you have to search a bit. But it always exist.

Comment: I'm not able to find it in any of the submenues, I'm using Nougat 32-bit on Bluestacks 10 if you can provide some direction on where I could find that?